# Third Party cookies are not working, I have tried - CookieManager.getInstance().acceptThirdPartyCookies();

Tags: android, webview

I have already checked many possible ways, but it doesn't work.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebView, true); 
    android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().acceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebView);
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? I have the same problem, but for me, it only happens on API lower than 30. Besides `setAcceptThirdPartyCookies`,  I also tried to `removeAllSessions`, `removeAllCookies`, `flush`, etc, but had no success. It doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebView, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
val webSettings = webView.settings
webSettings.domStorageEnabled = true
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true)
webSettings.mixedContentMode = WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW
```